# Syntax highlighting for INI format in Markdown

Tags: markdown, ini

I am trying to have syntax highlighted in a Markdown document for an INI format:

````
# ```ini
# [settings]
# compiler=gcc
# ```
````

But Markdown does not recognize it?
I commented the code to display the raw formatting on SO, not sure how to do that on SO.

Comment: CommonMark only defines `ini` as an [info string](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#info-string) that can be interpreted in any way (or ignored). It is often used for syntax highlighting, but that is not mandatory. Many Markdown implementations don't do syntax highlighting at all, and the ones that do don't all support the same languages. Which tool are you using, specifically?

Comment: I am using this in an extra `file.md` parsed by [Doxygen](https://doxygen.nl/), then by [Doxygen-awesome](https://jothepro.github.io/doxygen-awesome-css/index.html), then pushed on a Github Page.

Comment: So you're hosting Doxygen using the Doxygen-awesome theme on GitHub Pages? Doxygen and Doxygen-awesome are responsible for rendering the Markdown?

Comment: Correct. I have CMake do the work of configuring Doxygen, then I just have to use `set(DOXYGEN_HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET(...)` to add the doxygen awesome style sheet, and I can run the "make docs" command defined in my CMakeLists either locally or as a part of a Github workflow.